# Mentioning multiple user in chatter post

Tags: chatter-feed

```
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput1 = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput> ();
for (abc__c abcObj : abcList) {
    if (abc__c == NEW) {

        mentionSegmentInput.Id = a.id;
        for (Group memberList : opsList) {
            mentionSegmentInput1.Id = memberList.Id;
        }
    } else if (abc__c == ASSIGNED) {

        mentionSegmentInput.Id = a.id;
        mentionSegmentInput1.Id = b.id;
    }
    messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);

    messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput1);

    textSegmentInput.text = 'test';
    messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);
    input.subjectId = abc.Id;
    input.body = messageBodyInput;
}
```

but if any of a.id or b.id is blank or have same value , it is not posting the chatter

Comment: why not use null check and check if it exists in list then dont add?

Comment: Are you trying to add mentions to every entry in `opsList`? Your code doesn't do that; it overwrites `mentionSegmentInput1.Id`. If you're trying to add more than two mentions, you could be checking against a `Set<Id>`. If it's really only two, you just need to write a couple of `if` statements to check the conditions you want.